# What are conventions for filenames in Go?

Tags: go, naming-conventions

I could find the conventions for naming packages in Go: no underscore between words, everything lowercase.

Does this convention apply to the filenames too?

Do you also put one struct in one file as if you did for a java class and then name the file after the struct?

Currently, if I have a struct WebServer, I put it in a file web_server.go.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

There's a few guidelines to follow.

1. File names that begin with "." or "_" are ignored by the go tool
2. Files with the suffix `_test.go` are only compiled and run by the `go test` tool.
3. Files with os and architecture specific suffixes automatically follow those same constraints, e.g. `name_linux.go` will only build on linux, `name_amd64.go` will only build on amd64. This is the same as having a `//+build amd64` line at the top of the file

See the `go` docs for more details: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/ and https://golang.org/cmd/go/

Comment: What I should to do if I want to build for `unix` and `others`. E.g.  I can make two files `file_windows.go` and `file_others.go`. It works fine. But for `file_unix.go` and `file_others.go` it does'n' work. I don't want to create eight files `darwin freebsg linux openbsd netbsd dragonfly solaris android`.

Comment: @Jimb What about camelCase ?

Comment: @Fire: filenames are generally all lowercase in case, both for consistency and for systems with case-insensitive filesystems.

Comment: For anyone with the same question as @IvanBlack, this can be accomplished using build tags. See here for a nice overview of how to do that: https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool

Comment: @IanGustafson, sorry man, but your link doesn't work for me, and probably it doesn't work for anybody else.

Comment: @IvanBlack I just double-checked the link, and it works for me still, but here's a link to the official docs: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints

Answer (score 60):

In addition to the [answer provided by JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25162021/1923095), regular file names are lower case, short, and without any sort of underscore or space.  Generally, file names follow the same convention as package names.  See the [Package Names](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names) section of [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html).

See the [strconv package](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/strconv) for a good example.

Comment: what'd you give long files a name?  `mycommandsub1command.go` or `my_command_sub1command.go`, and what about `mycommandVO`

Comment: I would suggest underscores for long names. Have seen this in some good projects.

Answer (score 27):

Go is quite liberal in terms of how you organise your code within a package, usually it's whatever improves readability and understanding of your code. The best way to learn how this is done is to study the masters, i.e. have a browse though the standard library:

http://golang.org/src/pkg/

There are 2 rules I can think of however. When specifying code to be compiled for different platforms, you use the platform name as a suffix:

```
mypkg_linux.go         // only builds on linux systems
mypkg_windows_amd64.go // only builds on windows 64bit platforms
```

Also if you have a file called `server.go`, the tests for that file would be in `server_test.go`.

Comment: In the link you provided, I found use cases with the underscore: http://golang.org/src/pkg/compress/bzip2/move_to_front.go, http://golang.org/src/pkg/compress/flate/huffman_bit_writer.go, http://golang.org/src/pkg/compress/flate/reverse_bits.go.

Comment: I guess they won't use `_front`, `_writer` or `_bits` as significant suffixes in the future then!

Comment: I love Go, but the `go` tool is very restrictive about package structure (it's one of my favorite things about the language). It favors some very specific conventions (one package per folder [with at least one exception], the folder's package shares the same name as the folder [with at least one exception], full package import path matches the relative path from `$GOPATH`, some files are treated differently depending on their name format, etc)

Comment: @weberc2 The restrictions are analogous to Latex. First, I wanted to control my layout and other irrelevant details, until I realised that all that needs to be written is good content. Similarly, Go enables us to write good code and handles other details for us.

Comment: @david I agree. In retrospect I was unclear: I was responding to the answerer's statement `Go is quite liberal in terms of how you organise your code within a package`. Go is not liberal, it's quite restrictive. But that's a good thing.

Answer (score 11):

Usually underscore in filenames are used to assign platform/arch-only code, for example:

```
➜ cd $GOROOT/src/pkg/math/
➜ ls sqrt*s
sqrt_386.s  sqrt_amd64p32.s  sqrt_amd64.s  sqrt_arm.s
```

`sqrt_386.s` will only be read by the compiler on 32bit processors, `sqrt_amd64.s` on amd64, etc..

It can be any of the valid values of `GOOS` and/or `GOARCH` ([ref](http://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment).

`file_windows_amd64.go` will be only compiled on win64.

Answer (score 4):

Long all small caps for filenames is a terrible idea!

Filenames do not have semantic meaning at go - they are not imported or referenced. Code files in go are compiled to the package they are assigned to as one unit.

Since the article in effective go don't include limitations on muti word filenames except underscore (for build, ignore, test and compile purposes) mixedCaps are the best option for multi word filenames convention. And it's recommend by the same article "effective go"

Tl;dr:

```
- smallallcupspackagename
|- veryLongFileName.go
|- veryLongFileName_test.go
|- veryLongFileName_amd64_windows.go
```

Answer (score 1):

apart from all the other suggestions, the naming conventions should include (.). what it means is that if you have a module as "User", you are using routes, and models are defined inside the user module. Their name should be like user.models.go, user.route.go, user.service.go.
This is just clearer and easier to read.

Comment: This is not a convention. No delimiter is preffered.