# File name convention for compound words?

Tags: go, naming-conventions

Is there a common convention in Go to name files that contain compound words?

For example I wrote an implementation of the *Weighted Union Find* algorithm and put it into its own source file. How should I name the file?

```
// mixed case
weightedUnionFind.go

// lower case
weightedunionfind.go

// snake case
weighted_union_find.go
```

I found only a convention regarding [package names](https://blog.golang.org/package-names) and the following question about file naming conventions in general, [What are conventions for filenames in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161774/what-are-conventions-for-filenames-in-go).

Therefore I grepped through Go package source files and ended up with `weightedunionfind.go`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Although it's not formally specified in https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Overview - `snake_case` is the convention across the most of the standard library and most third party libraries.

Comment: Thanks. In the standard library I found only few examples and the didn't use underscores, e.g. `ast/commentmap.go`. I assumed that underscores are used only for tests and platform specific implementations.

Comment: There's still a big mix across the std. lib. Source file names are usually kept short, so in your case I would tend to call it `find.go` in package `weightedunion`.

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct answer; `_` does have a special meaning in golang, when it comes to conditional compilation   https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool . Kebab case too seems unpopular with gophers. This leaves the preferred choice to be `weightedunionfind.go`; not liking it personally, but not that bothered when working with a decent IDE. Quite like mixed case, but I haven't seen many examples from others. @elithrar's comments are spot on; the idea is to make better use of packages when you are tempted to name it long.