# Name for a generated go file

Tags: go, naming-conventions, code-generation

I'm generating a Go file (to include constants such as build version etc) so that the constants can be used in other packages.  I have a created a small tool that will create the file with `go generate` but am trying to think of an appropriate name so that

- It is obvious that it is generated, so if it is missing (on build) the user then knows to run `go generate`
- And I can then add the file to the .gitignore

My first guess is something like `version_GENERATED.go`

Any conventions I should be aware of or better suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a suffix like `_GENERATED` added to the file name does not hold any information until the file is generated, as the compiler will just give you "unrelated" errors like `"undefined: xxx"` (the compiler won't guess that if the identifier would exists, it would be in `version_GENERATED.go`).

For example the [`stringer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) generator generates files with name `type_string.go` where type is replaced with the name of the type it is generated for.

So I think simply following the [general guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161774/what-are-conventions-for-filenames-in-go) for file names is enough, except maybe use `_gen` or `_generated` suffix. Or if your tool is public and used by others too, then use the name of the tool as the suffix (like `stringer` does).

If you do want the user to get a talkative error message in case your generator is yet to be run, your generator may generate an exported constant whose name is talkative if included in an error message, like:

```
const MustRunStringerGenerator = 0
```

And in your program refer to it like:

```
var _ = MustRunStringerGenerator // Test if stringer has been run
```

If `stringer` has not yet been run, you'll see an error message:

```
undefined: MustRunStringerGenerator
```